# Import domain classes to GWT Project. Required Module?

Tags: gwt

Currently I'm developing a simple PoC for testing GWT with JPA. My entrypoint have a DataGrid GWT Component for show entity Jpa beans of my database example.

I have a common project with JPA entities (annotated POJO) and I have another project with only GWT classes neeeded.

Now, I created one Service to inject with Spring some Daos, and this run very well, but when I  return a list of some JPA Annotated Pojo, I get this exception:

[ERROR] Line 20: No source code is available for type  com.foo.domain.Product; did you forget to inherit a required module?

I added in other project a domain.gwt.xml with this code:

```
<module>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <source path="domain"></source>
</module>
```

And in my gwt project xml added this:

```
<inherits name='es.gerardribas.example.common.domain'/>
```

But doesn't run.

What's wrong???

Thanks!

Comment: "But doesn't run" - and where is the error? Path to domain.gwt.xml is "es/gerardribas/example/common/domain/domain.gwt.xml" ? And is the directory "es" with source code in your classpath during GWT-compilation?

Comment: In which folder is your modules's XML file? It must be in ``es.gerardribas.example.common``. Your client code should be in ``es.gerardribas.example.common.client`` and your domain code should be in ``es.gerardribas.example.common.domain``. But note that JPA entities might not work directly in GWT client side code if the source code for the annotation is not exposed directly. You have to either use gilead or maybe use RequestFactory and define Proxy interfaces for your JPA POJO's